# Starting a Service from Cmd.exe

Tags: command-line-interface, windows-service

I have a  WCF Service being hosted by a Windows Service.

How would I go about starting the service from the command line while passing the following arguments

The user I would like the service to logon as. I also need to pass in the password for the user.

I have previously been entering the values into services.msc but I find this tiresome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On which Windows release?

On recent ones, `sc.exe` is your friend here.

```
sc start ServiceName
sc stop ServiceName

sc config ServiceName option= value
```

The last one lets you set many things, amongst them the startup type and the service's logon user account (and password).

`sc` is odd in that, when using the `config` argument a space must follow each argument's equals sign.

Comment: You're the man. That is it.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, if you are always working locally (i.e. not remoting controlling services on other machines) you can use

```
net start "service name"
net stop "service name"
```

To expand on Massimo's answer, you can use service control (sc) to minipulate services on other machines in your domain:

```
sc \\serverName start "service name"
sc \\serverName stop "service name"
```